# Ruby on Rails model save rest_client no local database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, rest-client

I was wondering if there was a "proper" way to use RoR's MVC for doing all CRUD actions through something like rest_client. I won't have access to the DB but rather rest requests to do all CRUD actions.

Is there any way to define a model that contains all of the json data that would be returned on a get and put that into a model that can use Model.Save, Model.Create etc like a regular RoR application?

Would creating new methods def save, def create inside the ApplicationController work for this or not?

Edit: rest_client isn't required, just the ability to send json in post, get, delete and put with basic auth at the same time.

Edit 2: The only other idea I had was to use Active Model but those don't have save, delete etc methods. Would creating those that somehow tie into the ActionController::Base for wiring do this or not?

Comment: http://www.prestonlee.com/2007/12/29/rails-20-validations-without-extending-activerecordbase/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at activeresource http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html